# How to check if a value exists in an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects:

```js
var arrObj = [
    { a: "11", b: "Test1" },
    { a: "22", b: "Test2" },
    { a: "33", b: "Test1" },
    { a: "44", b: "Test3" },
];
```

I want to check if an object with a certain value for property `a` exists. If this exists then it should return the value of property `b`.
The value of `a` is always unique.

For example, if I am looking for `"11"`, then it should return `"Test1"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is exactly what you're looking for – it's better than `Array.prototype.filter` in this case because it will stop iterating as soon as the first match is found

```js
const data = [
  {"a": "11", "b":"Test1"},
  {"a": "22", "b":"Test2"},
  {"a": "33", "b":"Test1"},
  {"a": "44", "b":"Test3"},
]

console.log(data.find(x => x.a == 11).b)
// Test1
```

You should take care to handle the case when the queried item is **not found**, otherwise it's easy to encounter null/undefined errors -

```js
const data = [
  {"a": "11", "b":"Test1"},
  {"a": "22", "b":"Test2"},
  {"a": "33", "b":"Test1"},
  {"a": "44", "b":"Test3"},
]

const result = data.find(x => x.a == 11)

if (result == null)
  console.log("not found")
else
  console.log(result.b) // Test1
```

Comment: @DarrylNoakes thanks for the edit but your broke the program

Comment: Oh. _Why_ are you using loose comparison and comparing with a number, instead of just using a string?

Comment: Other than that, would you consider my edit acceptable? Still learning the "etiquette" around editing others' answers.

Comment: no worries. i always welcome edits, other users may differ. one thing i would strongly suggest is if an answer contains a code snippet, your edits should not change the meaning/output of the program. an exception to that is a bug. feel free to change it to `... === "11"` if you prefer. i didn't draw attention to that as it's not relevant for how `find` works.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you'll have same predefined properties `a` & `b` in your object, you can simply use **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** for your purpose. The following example demonstrates how you can use `find` method over an array of objects -

```js
const arrObj = [
    { a: "11", b: "Test1" },
    { a: "22", b: "Test2" },
    { a: "33", b: "Test1" },
    { a: "44", b: "Test3" },
];

// This will return the value of b if exists else undefined
const newArrObj = arrObj.find(obj => obj.a === "11")?.b;

console.log(newArrObj);
```

Comment: Nah, you want Array.prototype.find instead

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple solution to this problem, using only array methods. Methods like `filter`,`find`,`findIndex` can be used.

Below is a snippet of using `findIndex`. It will return the index of the object if the element exist in array, if not it will return -1

```js
var arrObj = [{
    "a": "11",
    "b": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "a": "22",
    "b": "Test2"
  },
  {
    "a": "33",
    "b": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "a": "44",
    "b": "Test3"
  }
];

var m = arrObj.findIndex(function(item) {
  return item.a === "11";
});
console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code is what you want:

```
var checkAndReturn =function (arr, n){
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i]["a"] === n) return arr[i]["b"];
        }
}
```

Use it:

```
checkAndReturn(arrObj, "11");
```

Answer (score 0):

just only use looping and check, hope this code is work for you!

```
arrObj.forEach(function(a) {
    a = Object.keys(a).map(function(key){
        return a[key];
    });

    a.forEach(function(v2, k2, d){

        if(d[0] == 11) {
            console.log(d[1]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a one-liner with arrow functions.

```js
var arrObj=[
    {"a" : "11", "b":"Test1"},
    {"a" : "22", "b":"Test2"},
    {"a" : "33", "b":"Test1"},
    {"a" : "44", "b":"Test3"}
];

console.log(arrObj.filter(obj => obj.a == 11))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

So,looking at that thread, this should do it for you.

```
var result = $.grep(arrObj, function(e){ return e.a == '11'; });
console.log(result[0].b);
```

You can make a function for first line and call it passing the Id you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see jQuery or `$.grep` mentioned anywhere